# Using Imagemagick composite api on google cloud function

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions, watermark

According to [this official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/imagemagick), google cloud offers built-in Imagemagick api.
But all the samples are using just `convert` api.

I tried to use Imagemagick's `composite` to create watermark, but firebase console gives me an error.

So the question is, does google offer just `convert` api from Imagemagick or does it also have support for other apis like `composite`

Comment: What sort of watermark do you want to create? You may be able to do it with convert.

Comment: I just found  `convert -draw 'image SrcOver 100,100 225,225 image.jpg' `  
Is this what you mean?
I want to overlay logo on images.

Comment: There are quite a lot of ways to do things in Imagemagick for instance another method: convert original.jpg watermark.png -gravity center -composite output.png This should keep any transparency in the watermark image.

Comment: composite is an old and limited method. I would suggest you use the more flexible convert syntax. For watermarking, you can see the equivalent commands at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#watermark

Answer (score 0):

You can use composite with convert in this way:

```
return spawn('convert', [tmpFilePath, tmpWatermarkPath, '-gravity', 'SouthEast', '-composite', tmpFilePath])
```